# PHP Loop start at 0 instead of 1

Tags: php, loops, thumbnails

Trying get an increasing number for each image which has to start at 0, its currently outputting from 1 and I don't know why!

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

```
  <div id="carousel">

    <ul class="thumbs">

   <?php $counts = 0 ; ?>

        <?php  foreach( $images as $image ): $counts++; ?>
            <li>
                <a data-slide-index="<?php echo $counts ;?>" href="">
<img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" /></a>
            </li>

<?php endforeach; ?>

    </ul>
  </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: should $count++ not be at the end of the for loop ?

Comment: You already raise the counter by 1, before you use it. Put the $counts++ part at the end.

Comment: `++$counts` wouldn't be right at all - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

Comment: Why don't you just use [for](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) intead of foreach? You're recreating the wheel with the counter.

Comment: @AaronW.http://3v4l.org/jJ80W

Comment: @user790454 OP wants it to start with zero, using `++$count` would never allow that

Comment: @AaronW. the question is `PHP Loop start at 0 instead of 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you are increamenting `$counts` before `echo`

so just do this :

```
<?php $counts = -1 ; ?>
```

or this:

```
foreach( $images as $image )
{
    echo '<li>
        <a data-slide-index="' . $counts . '" href="">
        <img src="' . $image['sizes']['thumbnail'] . '" alt="' . $image['alt'] . '" /></a>
    </li>';
    $counts++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach( $images as $image ): $counts++;
```

Is run on the first iteration. Thus

```
$counts = 0;
foreach( $images as $image ): $counts++;

$counts == 1 // true on first iteteration
```

You can either do

```
$counts = -1 // Code smell!
```

Or

```
<?php 
$counts = 0 ;  
foreach( $images as $i => $image )?>
<li>
  <a data-slide-index="<?php echo $i ?>" href="#">
     <img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" /></a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You increment `$counts` before you use it. You start it at 0 but as soon as you start the foreach and run `$counts++;` it becomes 1.

Move `$counts++;` to the end of the foreach loop.

```
<?php $counts = 0 ; ?>
<?php foreach( $images as $image ) : ?>
    <li>
        <a data-slide-index="<?php echo $counts; ?>" href="">
            <img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
        </a>
    </li>

    <?php $counts++; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<?php foreach( $images as $image ): $counts++; ?>
```

do

```
<?php $counts++; endforeach; ?>
```

to increment **after** the text is printed.

Answer (score 0):

Write your code like this :

```
<div id="carousel">

    <ul class="thumbs">

   <?php $counts = 0 ; ?>

        <?php  foreach( $images as $image ) { ?>
            <li>
                <a data-slide-index="<?php echo $counts ;?>" href="">
<img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" /></a>
            </li>



<?php  $counts++; }  ?>

    </ul>
  </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This is incorrect. You need to remove endforeach if you're going to switch to using braces.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
    <div id="carousel">

    <ul class="thumbs">

   <?php $counts = 0 ; ?>

        <?php  foreach( $images as $image ): $counts++; ?>
            <li>
                <a data-slide-index="<?php if($counts == 1){echo '0';}else {echo $counts 
 ;} ?>" href="">
<img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" /></a>
            </li>

<?php endforeach; ?>

    </ul>
  </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```